# TranslateTransition setBy do not work with RotateTransition

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using a `TranslateTransition` and `RotateTransition` to move a `Pane`. I want to rotate it and move it in parallel using a `ParallelTransition`; but when the animation starts, it only rotates. Here is my code:

```
//start movement 1
ttren2.setByX(-anchoTotal/2);
ttren2.play();
ttren2.setByX(0);
Thread.sleep(velocidadAjustada);
//movement 2
RotateTransition rota = new RotateTransition();
rota.setNode(tren2);
rota.setDuration(Duration.millis(velocidad/5));
rota.setByAngle(-90);
ttren2.setByY(365);
parallel.getChildren().add(rota);
parallel.getChildren().add(ttren2);
parallel.play();
ttren2.setByY(0);
ttren2.setByX(0);
Thread.sleep(velocidadAjustada);
//movement 3
rota.setByAngle(90);
ttren2.setByX(-((contador*123.5)+367));
parallel.play();
ttren2.setByX(0);
Thread.sleep(velocidadAjustada);
//movement 4
parallel.getChildren().clear();
ttren2.setByX((contador*123.5+367));
lista.get(minIndex).setDuration(Duration.millis(velocidad));
lista.get(minIndex).setByX((contador*123.5+367));
parallel.getChildren().addAll(lista.get(minIndex), ttren2);
parallel.play();
```

Movement 1 is fine, but movements 2 and 3 do not move the `Pane`; they only rotate it.

I tried changing the `getChildren().add` to `getChildren().addAll`, using thread sleep.
Also, I tried changing the `setBy` to `setTo`, and it worked; but when I use it, the following `setBy` does not work.

Comment: Do not `sleep()` on the JavaFX application thread. Please [edit] your question to explain your goal snd include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: You *must not* sleep on the FX Application Thread. This will prevent the UI from updating. And note that all values with a `set` method, such as `setByX()` are properties in the regular Java sense. So calling them twice in succession will just result in the property having the second value you pass. It's not really clear how this code is supposed to work.